# I want to plot my data and color depen on cluster

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to plot my k means algorithm in python but I don't understand how to plot it I want to plot it and the color is depend on their cluster,

I tried several code in the internet but I don't understand it 
and my x and y co-ordinates are sum[0] and sum[1] and my index for clustering is in centBaru variable.

```
   sum[0]=[30000,50000,50000,4000,......]
   sum[1]=[0.333333,0.12121,0.232,0.1212211,......]
   centBaru=contain index cluster
```

I want the output like when I use library sklearn.

```
  'plt.scatter(df['x'], df['y'], c= kmeans.labels_.astype(float), s=50, alpha=0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import  matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline 
s['x']: [30000,50000,50000,4000]
s['y']: [0.333333,0.12121,0.232,0.1212211]
s['centBaru']: [0,2,1,1]  # id of claster for each point

# so first point would be (x,y) = (30000, 0.33333) with color Red (i.e.  id of cluster = "0" 

cl = ['r','g','b']  # colors for different clusters


plt.scatter(x = s['x'],y = s['y'], c = [cl[x] for x in s['centBaru']])
```

it gives you result like this:
[image]

Comment: how does 'c': [10,200,100,100] work?, my cluster is based on list index, so when my centBaru index =0 thats mean sum1[0] is in cluster 1